# Windows 8.1 App causing high runtime broker memory and disk usage

Tags: c#, windows, memory, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Recently my app has been causing runtime broker to consume memory to the point where the system runs out of memory, i ran the profiler and also monitored the task manager, The memory consumed by the my App stays around 250 mb.
What can be the possible api calls / usage that might use runtime broker internally?

As my app itself is not consuming high memory i ruled out memory leaks.

Comment: Are you by chance using [Ad Rotator](https://github.com/Adrotator/AdrotatorV2)? In my app, it was causing the Runtime Broker issues you mention above. I ended up removing it and my app has been acting normally.

Comment: I am using AdRotator, but i have been using it since initial release of my app (OneCloudDrive), and this problem started after i made changes, which i have double checked. I will try to disable AdRotator to see if that helps.

Comment: *"...this problem started after i made changes"* - you may want to include your changes in your question above... otherwise we are just guessing at what happened.

Comment: I am still peeling the onion, will post an update soon.

Comment: If my file query returns many StorageFiles (1000s), then RuntimeBroker consumes tonnes of memory (up to 4gb). My unproven guess is that it is holding files in memory on behalf on my app.

Comment: Well I was never able to solve this. So app hangs randomly.

Comment: Processing a QueryResult in batches appears to mitigate the issue. That is to say, use storageFolder.getFilesAsync(query, startIndex, maxItemsToRetrieve) instead of storageFolder.getFilesAsync().